# javascript sum calculation not functioning

Tags: javascript, html, forms, cgi

I have a cgi form for employees to enter travel expenses.  I'm using javascript to automatically display & send calculated data.  The first (mileage) calculation on the form works.  I cannot get the 2nd (total) calculation to appear. The result I am looking for is-
Miles * Rate (0.555) = Mileage (works)
MileageExp + other input fields = TotalExpenses (not working)

Here is the javascript-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function totalexpense()
{
//mileage
a = document.event.Miles.value
b = document.event.Rate.value

c = a * b
z = c

document.event.Mileage.value = c.toFixed(2)

//total
d = document.event.Parking.value
e = document.event.Tolls.value
f = document.event.Plane.value
g = document.event.Train.value
h = document.event.Bus_Taxi.value
i = document.event.Lodging.value
j = document.event.Food.value
k = document.event.Other.value

l = z + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k

document.event.Total_Expenses.value = l.toFixed(2)

}
</script>
```

The browser says there is an error in the `document.event.Total_Expenses.value = l.toFixed(2)` line.

HTML-

```
<p align="left" class="bold"><span class="style8">Mileage:</span><br>
Miles:
          <input name="Miles" size="10"> 
     X rate: 
       <input name="Rate" size="10" value="0.555" onblur="totalexpense();">
= 
       <input name="Mileage" size="10" readonly=true>
</p>

<p align="left">Parking:</span><br>
            <input name="Parking" size="10" onblur="totalexpense();">
</p>

<p align="left">Tolls:</span><br>
            <input name="Tolls" size="10" onblur="totalexpense();">
</p>

<p align="left">Airline Tickets:</span><br>
            <input name="Plane" size="10" onblur="totalexpense();">
</p>

<p align="left">Train:</span><br>
            <input name="Train" size="10" onblur="totalexpense();" >
</p>

<p align="left">Bus/Taxi:</span><br>
            <input name="Bus_Taxi" size="10" onblur="totalexpense();" >
</p>

<p align="left">Lodging:</span><br>
            <input name="Lodging" size="10" onblur="totalexpense();" > 
            Accomodations with- <input name="Accomodations_With" type="text"    size="40" />
</p>

<p align="left" class="bold"><span class="style8">Food/Beverage:</span><br>
            <input name="Food" size="10" onblur="totalexpense();" >
</p>

<p align="left">Other Expenses:</span><br>
            <input name="Other" size="10" onblur="totalexpense();" >
</p>

    <p align="left" class="bold"><span class="style8">Other Expense Notes:</span><br>
                  <span class="main style22">
                  <textarea name="Other_Expense_Notes" cols="50" rows="3" class="fieldbkgrd"></textarea>
                </span>
</p>

<h3>Total Expenses:<br>
            <input name="Total_Expenses" size="10" READONLY>
```

Comment: ie says "object doesn't support this property or method"  then the line number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the values from strings to numbers - .toFixed only works on a number.

```
document.event.Total_Expenses.value = Number(l).toFixed(2);
```

The reason your code worked with the mileage is because the 0.555 was cast to an integer in:

```
c = a * b; (c = # * 0.555)
```

You then do the "addition" which was treated like a concatenation:

```
z + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k;
```

This converted the int to a string. Thus:

```
document.event.Total_Expenses.value = l.toFixed(2);
```

failed because the type cast was now a string.

If you want to convert a value explicitly then you need to use parseInt();

```
d = parseInt(document.event.Parking.value);
```

Comment: Had both as readonly = true first, the both as READONLY, then tried with no readonly on both.  thanks for the closing advise... I'll correct that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the values from strings to numbers - .toFixed only works on a number.

```
document.event.Total_Expenses.value = Number(l).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: That got the Mileage to display in the Total box.  But none of the other values are being added.

Comment: try converting them all to Numbers! - c = Number(a) * Number(b); etc.

Comment: Did that from Shawns comment above and it worked.  thanks bob!

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name="Total_Expenses" size="10" READONLY>
```

you set it as read only so you cannot set a value to read only elements, that's my best guess

Comment: I removed the READONLY and still get same error.  The 1st calculation has readonly and functions ok.

Comment: READONLY will stop you changing the value using the control, but JavaScript can still set the values programmatically in the background.

Comment: then there is probably a type mismatch of strings and numbers. You can pareInt.